# restrict create/update/delete to requests with a user only

Tags: parse-platform

In Parse.com client APIs, it is possible to perform create/update/delete on object of any class. It would be good to set a minimal level of security that restrict these operations only to requests that are made by a `Parse.User`. This way, someone with access to say your REST or JS key can't just spam create or delete a ton of objects in your database.

I have 2 working solutions but they seem a tad too complicated for something so simple. If you know of a simpler way to accomplish this on Parse.com, please let me know.

Solution 1: Create a `RegularUser` role and assign all your users that role. Set up class level permission to this role. Undefined users (from requests made without a user) naturally do not have this role, thus access is revoked.

Solution 2: Create `beforeSave` and `beforeDelete` cloud code for every class and reject all requests without a user.

I'm pretty new to Parse and I have a feeling that I've missed a simple setting somewhere that lets you lock down your data for logged in users only. Please point that out if that is the case. If you are experienced in Parse.com and in your experience, there is no simpler way, I'd appreciate the confirmation as well. Thanks

Comment: On another thought, you fear that your backend will be spammed by creation (or deletion) of objects and you think restricting access to only a `user` will prevent it. What if someone creates a `user` account AND THEN starts spamming?

Comment: Hi Akshay, yea that will have to be taken care of too. I'm at an early phase of my app and the signup is restricted. I just want a minimal layer of security in place both to prevent spammers and to limit the effect my own dumb mistakes in various bootstrapping scripts.

Comment: Hi, If the number of `users` are small, I would recommend you to set some permissions manually. Click on `Security` for the class you want to protect, you will see fields like `Get` , `Find` , `Update` etc. All you need to do is paste the `ObjectId` of a particular user in the provided fields, then only that user will be able to perform that operation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this a bit late, but I thought I would answer to help out other readers. Like Akshay pointed out, you should definitely set the appropriate Class Level Permissions. But I think what you were getting at can be addressed through ACLs, as suggested by the Parse docs: https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#security-access-control-lists

You can set different types of ACLs for each class, or if you only want to allow users to access their own objects, it's really easy to implement that across all classes:

> To make it super easy to create user-private ACLs for every object, we
>   have a way to set a default ACL that will be used for every new object
>   you create:

In Swift for iOS:

```
PFACL.setDefaultACL(PFACL(), withAccessForCurrentUser: true)
```

I have this set up in my app's AppDelegate, which has the effect that any object the user creates can only be read/updated/deleted by that user.